# How relevant are negative examples for a Unet segmentation model?

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am working with a Unet segmentation model for medical image analysis, and I would like to know how important are negative examples (with empty masks) for my model to learn that some images are 100% negatives. I am asking this because I took a bunch of negative and added to my dataset, some kind of hard negative mining, and still, I am getting a lot of false positives. Does Unet learn anything with negative examples? Is there any other way to force my model to learn these 'negative' features?

If you could also provide relevant information about this (articles, papers, questions) I would highly appreciate it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Data balance is very important between classes. How much data do you have per class? I recommend you do some data augmentation for the class that has less data or you can write a custom batch generator.